# In ES6 is destructuring Class Instance properties permitted?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Suppose I have the following code:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 'something';
    }

    someMethod() {
        // Is this legal?
        let { a, b } = this;
    }
}
```

Is the destructuring assignment in `someMethod` legal?

My gut feeling is that it is fine, but I have seen no reference to this usage in any docs. It currently works in Babel, but presumably because under the hood Babel is transpiling the class into a function. My understanding is that (almost) everything in JS prototypically inherits from Object, so I might expect this to be true for Classes and Class instances too.

The only reference I've seen to what happens under the hood [is here](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) and specifies that the JS engine calls the internal method `ToObject` which will only throw a TypeError when it encounters `null` or `undefined`. But the [`ToObject` docs](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-toobject) don't explicitly mention class instances.

Comment: unrelated to your question, but do you any particular reason you used let instead of var?

Comment: yes it is, but `()` after `Foo` isn't

Comment: many coders will just use `let` every time because they heard it was a good idea; regardless of whether any blocks are in-play or not... you gotta problem wit `let`?

Comment: @VladNicula seems like an odd question for a minimal (almost) working example that is clearly designed to show the principal of what the question is about

Comment: @VladNicula - any reason not to?

Comment: keep in mind that making a new object will bust your inheritance  on an other-wise identical object...

Comment: @JaromandaX - Yes you're right, typo - fixed

Comment: @VladNicula - as per the comment from @dandavis we've chosen to avoid using `var` altogether on this project and have this set up in the eslint rules. Didn't specifically mean to write it here, just in the habit now I guess.

Comment: @dandavis can you clarify what you mean about breaking inheritance?

Comment: i mean that even though `JSON.stringify()` on both will be `{"a":1,"b":"something"}`, one will inherit prototype methods and one will not. you probably knew that; i'm just clarifying for the kids out there...

Comment: @all, I was just curios if there's a perf benefit of sorts. It's interesting how most of you got a negative vibe from my question :)

Comment: @dandavis on both? `let { a, b } = this;` is a destructuring assigment, so produces two block scoped variables `a` and `b` with their values copied from `this` not another object, or am I missing something? :)

Comment: yeah, i was up too late and gotta mixed up. i do think the syntax can be less readable than repeating keys...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Destructuring objects is explicitly allowed and is a feature.
`this` merely refers to an object. There's nothing special about it.
As long as `this` refers to an object, this is absolutely fine. *

* `this` may *not* refer to an object depending on how you call `someMethod`, e.g. `Foo.someMethod.apply(null)`. But then you really have bigger problems anyway.

Comment: sure thanks, just wanted explicit clarification really as other examples only deal with plain objects not class instances

Comment: @baseten Your curiosity is understandable. :) Broadly speaking, the `class` syntax is a sugar over the existing ES5 approach of using function constructors with only a few semantic differences, so you end up with essentially the same thing: an object with properties you can access and destructure. (Main differences are minor, things like that classes must be invoked using the `new` keyword, class declarations aren't hoisted, prototype properties aren't enumerable, subclassing works a bit differently etc.)